# Can anyone tell me why I can't use Padding with this AES implementation?

Tags: java, encryption, aes, padding

I'm trying to write an app where users should be able to chose from the algorithms modes of operation (CBC, CTR ... )

I'm using this code (which is not written by me) for AES encryption but I noticed that I can use it only with NoPadding and I don't understand why.

```
public void setPassword(String password) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    this.password = password.getBytes("UTF-16LE");
    debug("Using password: ", this.password);
}

public void encrypt(int version, String fromPath, String toPath) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fromPath));
        debug("Opened for reading: " + fromPath);
        out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(toPath));
        debug("Opened for writing: " + toPath);

        encrypt(version, in, out);
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
    }
}

public void encrypt(int version, InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    try {
        byte[] text = null;

        ivSpec1 = new IvParameterSpec(generateIv1());
        aesKey1 = new SecretKeySpec(generateAESKey1(ivSpec1.getIV(), password), CRYPT_ALG);
        ivSpec2 = new IvParameterSpec(generateIV2());
        aesKey2 = new SecretKeySpec(generateAESKey2(), CRYPT_ALG);
        debug("IV1: ", ivSpec1.getIV());
        debug("AES1: ", aesKey1.getEncoded());
        debug("IV2: ", ivSpec2.getIV());
        debug("AES2: ", aesKey2.getEncoded());

        out.write("AES".getBytes("UTF-8")); // Heading.
        out.write(version); // Version.
        out.write(0); // Reserved.
        if (version == 2) { // No extensions.
            out.write(0);
            out.write(0);
        }
        out.write(ivSpec1.getIV()); // Initialization Vector.

        text = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE + KEY_SIZE];
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey1, ivSpec1);
        cipher.update(ivSpec2.getIV(), 0, BLOCK_SIZE, text);
        cipher.doFinal(aesKey2.getEncoded(), 0, KEY_SIZE, text, BLOCK_SIZE);
        out.write(text); // Crypted IV and key.
        debug("IV2 + AES2 ciphertext: ", text);

        hmac.init(new SecretKeySpec(aesKey1.getEncoded(), HMAC_ALG));
        text = hmac.doFinal(text);
        out.write(text); // HMAC from previous cyphertext.
        debug("HMAC1: ", text);

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey2, ivSpec2);
        hmac.init(new SecretKeySpec(aesKey2.getEncoded(), HMAC_ALG));
        text = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE];
        int len, last = 0;
        while ((len = in.read(text)) > 0) {
            cipher.update(text, 0, BLOCK_SIZE, text);
            hmac.update(text);
            out.write(text); // Crypted file data block.
            last = len;
        }
        last &= 0x0f;
        out.write(last); // Last block size mod 16.
        debug("Last block size mod 16: " + last);

        text = hmac.doFinal();
        out.write(text); // HMAC from previous cyphertext.
        debug("HMAC2: ", text);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        throw new GeneralSecurityException(JCE_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE, e);
    }
}

public void decrypt(String fromPath, String toPath) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fromPath));
        debug("Opened for reading: " + fromPath);
        out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(toPath));
        debug("Opened for writing: " + toPath);

        decrypt(new File(fromPath).length(), in, out);
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
    }
}

public void decrypt(long inSize, InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    try {
        byte[] text = null, backup = null;
        long total = 3 + 1 + 1 + BLOCK_SIZE + BLOCK_SIZE + KEY_SIZE + SHA_SIZE + 1 + SHA_SIZE;
        int version;

        text = new byte[3];
        readBytes(in, text); // Heading.
        if (!new String(text, "UTF-8").equals("AES")) {
            throw new IOException("Invalid file header");
        }

        version = in.read(); // Version.
        if (version < 1 || version > 2) {
            throw new IOException("Unsupported version number: " + version);
        }
        debug("Version: " + version);

        in.read(); // Reserved.

        if (version == 2) { // Extensions.
            text = new byte[2];
            int len;
            do {
                readBytes(in, text);
                len = ((0xff & (int) text[0]) << 8) | (0xff & (int) text[1]);
                if (in.skip(len) != len) {
                    throw new IOException("Unexpected end of extension");
                }
                total += 2 + len;
                debug("Skipped extension sized: " + len);
            } while (len != 0);
        }

        text = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE];
        readBytes(in, text); // Initialization Vector.
        ivSpec1 = new IvParameterSpec(text);
        aesKey1 = new SecretKeySpec(generateAESKey1(ivSpec1.getIV(), password), CRYPT_ALG);
        debug("IV1: ", ivSpec1.getIV());
        debug("AES1: ", aesKey1.getEncoded());

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey1, ivSpec1);
        backup = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE + KEY_SIZE];
        readBytes(in, backup); // IV and key to decrypt file contents.
        debug("IV2 + AES2 ciphertext: ", backup);
        text = cipher.doFinal(backup);
        ivSpec2 = new IvParameterSpec(text, 0, BLOCK_SIZE);
        aesKey2 = new SecretKeySpec(text, BLOCK_SIZE, KEY_SIZE, CRYPT_ALG);
        debug("IV2: ", ivSpec2.getIV());
        debug("AES2: ", aesKey2.getEncoded());

        hmac.init(new SecretKeySpec(aesKey1.getEncoded(), HMAC_ALG));
        backup = hmac.doFinal(backup);
        text = new byte[SHA_SIZE];
        readBytes(in, text); // HMAC and authenticity test.
        if (!Arrays.equals(backup, text)) {
            throw new IOException("Message has been altered or password incorrect");
        }
        debug("HMAC1: ", text);

        total = inSize - total; // Payload size.
        if (total % BLOCK_SIZE != 0) {
            throw new IOException("Input file is corrupt");
        }
        if (total == 0) { // Hack: empty files won't enter block-processing
                          // for-loop below.
            in.read(); // Skip last block size mod 16.
        }
        debug("Payload size: " + total);

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey2, ivSpec2);
        hmac.init(new SecretKeySpec(aesKey2.getEncoded(), HMAC_ALG));
        backup = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE];
        text = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE];
        for (int block = (int) (total / BLOCK_SIZE); block > 0; block--) {
            int len = BLOCK_SIZE;
            if (in.read(backup, 0, len) != len) { // Cyphertext block.
                throw new IOException("Unexpected end of file contents");
            }
            cipher.update(backup, 0, len, text);
            hmac.update(backup, 0, len);
            if (block == 1) {
                int last = in.read(); // Last block size mod 16.
                debug("Last block size mod 16: " + last);
                len = (last > 0 ? last : BLOCK_SIZE);
            }
            out.write(text, 0, len);
        }
        out.write(cipher.doFinal());

        backup = hmac.doFinal();
        text = new byte[SHA_SIZE];
        readBytes(in, text); // HMAC and authenticity test.
        if (!Arrays.equals(backup, text)) {
            throw new IOException("Message has been altered or password incorrect");
        }
        debug("HMAC2: ", text);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        throw new GeneralSecurityException(JCE_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE, e);
    }
}
```

When I try to encrypt a file using PCS5Padding I get this error:

```
Output buffer too short: 32 bytes given, 48 bytes needed 
javax.crypto.ShortBufferException: Output buffer too short: 32 bytes given, 48 bytes needed
```

Comment: That is a massive pile of code. Please can you simplify it to the minimum code necessary to reproduce your problem. Oh, and can you tell us what actually happens when you try to use padding?

Comment: Do **not** allow ECB mode, it is insecure.  Cut down your application to just CBC mode with minimal options, and get that working.  Only when the minimal app works correctly should you add more options.

Comment: @rossum I don't use ECB, it doesn't even work with it. I made a mistake when I wrote the question first time.

Comment: @Duncan Jones I forgot to write the error I get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting that exception, because, as the message says, the output buffer is too short.

I don't know which line the exception is thrown at (you didn't post the stack trace), but it seems that the code only handles ciphertexts of a specific length, and fails when padding is applied (as PKCS#5 padding can add a whole block).

What is the point of encrypting the "main" encryption key? It doesn't add any security but is more complex. As per the old adage, complexity is the enemy of security.

Also watch out for the dangers of home-rolled (or copy-pasted-off-the-internet) cryptography. I can immediately spot at least one vulnerability – the MAC-then-pad sequence allows a padding oracle attack. You're much better off using a tried-and-tested solution, such as [Keyczar](http://www.keyczar.org/).

Comment: Thank you ! I'm not so good in understanding how to write it myself and I'm under time pressure. I wrote the interface and it does what I need but I was curious why I can't use padding. Your explanation seems good enough. Do you know something like Keyczar that has DES ecryption also ?

Comment: You start with a plaintext, then you add padding.  What you encrypt is plaintext + padding.  Hence your output buffer needs to have enough space to hold both.  Since padding is always added, you will always have an output from encryption that is longer than the initial plaintext.

Comment: @StoicaDan I would be very, very surprised if Keyczar supported DES. DES keys are so weak that they can be brute forced in a matter of few hours on a modern home computer.

Comment: @ntoskrnl I know DES is weak, but what I'm trying to do is an app that allows the users to chose which encryption algorithm they want to use.

Comment: @StoicaDan What's the point of that? Relying on a single known-to-work algorithm (i.e. AES) is a better idea, particularly when considering the fact that most users don't understand anything about cryptography and won't be able to pick a sensible combination on their own.

Comment: "most users don't understand anything about cryptography" - that's the point. If users can see more options the app will make them curious and maybe they will be more interested in cryptography.

Comment: @ntoskrnl " the MAC-then-pad sequence allows a padding oracle attack" - isn't it the other way around ? I read that: (quote from wiki) "Padding oracle attacks can be avoided by making sure that the attacker cannot gain knowledge about the removal of the padding bytes. This can be accomplished by verifying a MAC or digital signature before removal of the padding bytes"

Comment: @StoicaDan When decrypting, you have to verify the MAC before removing padding (as the Wiki page says). When encrypting, you have to generate the MAC after adding padding (as I said).

Comment: @ntoskrnl I found the main source of my code. It is the free open source program AES Crypt. The flaws in the code are mostly discussed on [the forum](http://forums.packetizer.com/viewtopic.php?f=72&t=281). I thought you might be curious.

Comment: @StoicaDan What damiank described is basically just a dictionary attack. This is why key derivation is such an important topic when using passwords. The code in the question above does not do proper key strengthening.